# MongoDB replica set converts to standalone on machine restart (MacOS)

Tags: mongodb

I figured out how to convert my local Mongo database into a single replica set so that I can so some testing with change streams. However after a machine restart it's back to a standalone. Running MacOS Mojave if that matters.

Is there a way to have it remain a replica set even after a machine reboot? Seems like a big pain to have to convert it every time i restart my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I battled with this for a while, but eventually what worked was:

editing `mongodb.conf` (located at `/usr/local/etc/mongodb.conf` on MacOS) and appending the following at the end:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs
```

restarting my machine.

That was it.

For some reason i couldn't use `brew services restart mongodb`, which i still don't understand, but it works now!